# Dragstart not getting invoked after reordering the elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events, aurelia

I am trying to create a list which can be reordered by dragging the items in it.

When I drag an element for the first time `dragstart.trigger="drag($event)"` invokes the `drag(e)`. In `drag(e)` I set data of the element dragged.

On dropping the dragged element `drop.trigger="drop($event)"` invokes `drop(e)`.
In `drop(e)` I get the dragged element and remove it from the list/parent element `<ul>`.
After that I insert the dragged element to the dropped location.

The problem is once a element is dragged. I cannot able to drag it again to different target because the `dragstart.trigger="drag($event)"` is not invoking the `drag(e)`.

How can I invoke `dragstart.trigger="drag($event)"`?

```
<ul id="columns" drop.trigger="drop($event)" dragover.trigger="allowDrop($event)">
    <li id="item1" class="column" draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="drag($event)" dragend.trigger="dragend($event)"><header>A</header></li>
    <li id="item2" class="column" draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="drag($event)" dragend.trigger="dragend($event)"><header>B</header></li>
    <li id="item3" class="column" draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="drag($event)" dragend.trigger="dragend($event)"><header>C</header></li>
    <li id="item4" class="column" draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="drag($event)" dragend.trigger="dragend($event)"><header>D</header></li>
    <li id="item5" class="column" draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="drag($event)" dragend.trigger="dragend($event)"><header>E</header></li>
</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
drag(e) {
  console.log('handleDragStart');
  // Target element is the source node.
  this.dragSrcEl = e.currentTarget;
  console.log('dragSrcEl :', this.dragSrcEl);

  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.currentTarget.outerHTML);
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('dragElem');
  return true;
}

allowDrop(e) {
  console.log('handleDragover');
  e.preventDefault();
}

dragend() {
  console.log('handleDragEnd');
}

drop(e) {
  console.log('handleDrop');

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  // Don't do anything if dropping the same column we're dragging.  
  if (this.dragSrcEl != e.srcElement) {
    e.currentTarget.removeChild(this.dragSrcEl);

    let dropHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
    e.srcElement.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin',dropHTML)
  }
  e.currentTarget.classList.remove('over');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `dragstart` is not invoked after reordering the elements, is because you're not really *reordering* them. You're actually removing the dragged element and then inserting a new copy of it.

This new copy is not handled by aurelia's composition engine, therefore not compiled, and so any aurelia-specific expressions in the html will not do anything. `.trigger` is simply a dead tag at that point.

Drag/drop is kind of a special beast and has never been particularly simple to implement in a natural way, especially when there's all kind of custom framework behavior attached to these elements.

**You have 3 options here:**

1. Do not use aurelia's `trigger` and instead just use `el.addEventListener` both when you first create them, and then when you create new copies.
2. Use aurelia's `ViewEngine` to re-compile (parts of) your view whenever you drop an element so that `.trigger` is processed which, under the hood, really kind of just does `el.addEventListener` anyway
3. Turn this into custom element with a `repeat.for` and let Aurelia handle the html side of things.

Now option 1 would certainly be the quickest way to get it to work, and option 2 would be slightly more robust and tricky to do, but both are quite hacky.

I'm a strong advocate of utilizing the framework rather than hacking around it, because things will be easier to maintain on the longterm and you can more easily add additional fancy behavior as the project evolves.

It may seem much more involved than what you are doing now, but by engaging more of the framework to handle the low-level stuff, you'll have "living" draggable elements with a fully functional Aurelia that you can do much more things with.

**So here's just one example of how you might approach option 3:**

In app.js, make your columns into a list of javascript objects:

```
items = [
  { text: "A", id: "item1" },
  { text: "B", id: "item2" },
  { text: "C", id: "item3" },
  { text: "D", id: "item4" },
  { text: "E", id: "item5" }
];
```

In app.html, pass those items to the `columns` custom element (to keep the html similar to your example i'll use `as-element`)

```
<template>
  <require from="./resources/elements/columns"></require>
  <ul as-element="columns" items.bind="items"></ul>
</template>
```

In resources/elements/columns.js, work against individual items viewmodels instead of against the html elements:

```
import { customElement, children, bindable } from "aurelia-templating";

@customElement("columns")
export class Columns {
  // keeps a list of the viewmodels of the direct "li" children
  @children("li") children;

  // the columns
  @bindable() items;

  // the currently dragged column
  dragColumn;

  // the customEvent we dispatch from the child "column" element
  handleColDragStart(e) {
    // the viewmodel we passed into the customEvent
    this.dragColumn = e.detail.column;
  }

  allowDrop(e) {
    console.log("handleDragover");
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  drop(e) {
    console.log("handleDrop");

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    // source drag index
    let dragIdx = this.children.indexOf(this.dragColumn);

    // if we can't resolve to a sibling (e.g. dropped on or outside the list),
    // naively drop it at index 0 instead
    let dropIdx = 0;

    // try to find the drop target
    let dropTarget = e.srcElement;
    while (dropTarget !== document.body) {
      let dropTargetVm = dropTarget.au && dropTarget.au.controller && dropTarget.au.controller.viewModel;
      if (dropTargetVm) {
        dropIdx = this.children.indexOf(dropTargetVm);
        break;
      } else {
        dropTarget = dropTarget.parentElement;
      }
    }

    if (dragIdx !== dropIdx) {
      // only modify the order in the array of javascript objects;
      // the repeat.for will re-order the html for us
      this.items.splice(dropIdx, 0, this.items.splice(dragIdx, 1)[0]);
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

In resources/elements/columns.html, just listen for the customEvent we dispatch from the `column` element and other than that only handle `drop`:

```
<template id="columns" drop.trigger="drop($event)" dragover.trigger="allowDrop($event)">
  <require from="./column"></require>
  <li as-element="column" repeat.for="col of items" column.bind="col" coldragstart.trigger="handleColDragStart($event)">
  </li>
</template>
```

In resource/elements/column.js handle the `dragstart` and `dragend` events, then dispatch a customEvent with a reference to the viewModel (so you don't have to deal with the html too much):

```
import { customElement, bindable } from "aurelia-templating";
import { inject } from "aurelia-dependency-injection";

@customElement("column")
@inject(Element)
export class Column {
  el;
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  @bindable() column;

  dragstart(e) {
    this.el.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("coldragstart", {
        bubbles: true,
        detail: {
          column: this
        }
      })
    );
    return true;
  }
}
```

Finally, in resources/elements/column.html just listen for the `dragstart` event:

```
<template draggable="true" dragstart.trigger="dragstart($event)">
  <header>${column.text}</header>
</template>
```

The part of this solution that might look a bit strange to you, also the part that I still consider a bit hacky, is where we try to get the ViewModel via `el.au.controller.viewModel`.

This is something you "just need to know". A custom element / html behavior always has an `au` property on it that contains a reference to the behavior instance with the controller, view, etc.

This is essentially the easiest (and sometimes the only) way to "get a hold of" aurelia when working directly against the html. With things like drag/drop I don't believe there is any way to avoid this, as there is unfortunately no native aurelia support for it.